# Error 401 when trying fetch data using custom API with POST method

Tags: c#, reactjs, web, fetch-api, http-status-code-401

My friend and I are working on a college project (Reservations related web app) using React and C#.
Basically he made an API where users must input their data and after submitting, their data should be successfully sent to database. In my case, I get error 401 after submitting the data although I checked my JWT token and it's the same one I got after logging in. I tried this using Postman and it worked. I am curious why it won't work on my browser with the code submitted down below.
Thank everyone who can help. I am sorry if someone would find this question stupid but I'm relatively new to web development and I don't know how to fix this issue.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
        const data = {
            userEmail: Cookies.get('email'),
            userPhoneNumber: phone,
            town: city,
            country: country,
            street: street,
            houseNumber: houseNumber,
            postalCode: postalCode,
            businessName: jobName,
            businessIdentificationNumber: 0, 
            businessType: 0, 
            businessActivities: [
                {
                    nameOfActivity: "string", 
                    descriptionOfActivity: "string", 
                    price: 0
                }
            ],
            workingDays: Object.values(workingDays),
            startingHours: Object.values(workingHours).map(hours => hours.open),
            endingHours: Object.values(workingHours).map(hours => hours.close)
        };
    
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/business/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    };
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong in what you've provided that I can see. Since you have a working example through Postman, you should check the outgoing request to see everything that is set. Similarly, check in your React app how it appears when it's being sent there. Whatever is different should be migrated over to React. It might not hurt to double check that you're sending it to the correct URL. For readability you should consider adopting async/await.

Comment: Open up browser's dev tool, call the API through your web app, check both network section also console section. These places you might find why.

Comment: CORS error returns 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is CORS error. Try this in your API:

```
services.AddCors(options => {
   options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
   builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

And then:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

Allowing all origins may not be the best practice, but if it's working, the issue may lie in the CORS configuration you've implemented.

Comment: Thanks. This solved problem with error messages on my browsers.
Unfortunately, I still get Error 401 somehow when trying to fetch my API.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a CORS error. The 401 response code is sent by the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when your backend isn't configured with CORS. Verify if your API has CORS configured (usually it's simple to configure).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if it's because of CORS since we've already had problems with it at the beginning of our project. I used Firefox CORS extension that solved some issues for me, but it didn't help with this API. Is there any tutorial on configuring CORS successfully in C#?

Comment: Here's our backend code that implements CORS logic. My friend told me that he thinks everything should work fine with it: [C# Backend CORS code](https://pastebin.com/QcNAZpRQ)

Comment: Huum, everything seems ok. Is your front-end running on the 44491 port?

Comment: Yes...
It says this when I run it from VS Code:
Local:            https://localhost:44491

Comment: Here are also the error messages I get in Chrome and Firefox: [Chrome](https://ibb.co/TYPX52w)
[Firefox](https://ibb.co/BGJNHQv)